# `ENOENT: no such file or directory` error when installing ReactJS in M1 Mac

Tags: install, path

I tried to install ReactJS on an M1 Mac but encountered this error:

```
prabhav@Prabhavs-MacBook-Air ~ % node --version
v18.17.1
prabhav@Prabhavs-MacBook-Air ~ % npm --version
9.6.7
prabhav@Prabhavs-MacBook-Air ~ % npm install -g create-react-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /path
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/path'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
    
npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /path/to/your/directory/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

Path of node and npm: `/usr/local/bin`

path added to `.zshrs` : `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a directory in the root in any version of macOS that runs on an M1.

Instructions found at the [Create React App website](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) indicate that's not how you're supposed to start the development.  These instructions:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```